# block and expression must have a const value error

Tags: c++, eigen3

I would like to create a matrix B from a block of matrix A. The size of A changes, so I'm trying to achieve the following

```
Eigen::MatrixXd B(A.block<3,N>(0,0));
```

where N is columns number of A. I get this error `the expression must have constant value.` How can I solve this problem? I've tried to use `const_cast<>` but I still get the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd B = A.block(0, 0, 3, N);
```

The API documentation of eigen is [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/).
If `N` is a variable, it can't be used as a template function argument (`<3,N>`) because those must be compile-time constants (the compiler generates/instanciates a version of the function `block` for each combination or template arguments.)